# I'm trying to learn c# using some unity classes but I'm having some problems

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm taking a class on making 2d games in unity, but unity won't open the game file. The error message is: *Project path does not exist C:\users\Ohy0y\oneDrive\unity\NewUnityProject*. Please note that the unity folder is not official, it is made by me. I have updated unity, deleted every previous version of unity, and tried to redirect the path into an empty folder.

This is my first day learning unity so I may be missing something obvious, please answer if possible!

Answer (score 2):

A "game file" does not exist in Unity. In Unity, you have a specific folder structure. The project folder is the folder your Assets, ProjectSettings, Packages,... folder is inside.

In Unity Hub, remove the project you are trying to open from the list of projects and add it again by chosing your project folder (the one containing the Asset folder and such).

If that doesn't work for you, please specify why and try the following step:
In your project folder go into the ProjectSettings folder and open the file "ProjectVersion.txt" and tell me what the first line sais (m_EditorVersion: xxx). This is the project version, i.e. what Unity Version was used to create the project. That version should match the Untiy version you have installed.

Also, gernerally speaking, Unity Answers is the better platform for you to get quick answers to simple Unity related questions.

Comment: To the last point: Unity Answers is kind of [abandoned by the moderators](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1568194/answers-abandoned.html) and is also not really maintained anymore ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your Game (Game File), you need to create a build first.

[image]

[image]

But of course you need to build a working scene first. If you have problems just opening the project with unity, i would try making a new project outside onedrive.